# Etiquette on "rush" answers

Tags: discussion, etiquette, fastest-gun

I've just been wondering what the etiquette or acceptable behaviour is on this - to be honest it stems from a minor irritation with seeing people do this, but here it is:

I frequently see certain users answering questions almost immediately after they are posted, but the answers are one-liners that seldom make sense (they don't always do this of course, but even if its occasional, it tends to always be the same users). They then will spend the next few minutes (usually more or less within the "grace period", as I understand it), actually fleshing out their answer into something useful. If the first answer is downvoted or receives a negative comment, the reaction is often a little less than polite (and usually only after a few more edits have been made, which seems to "justify" it).

It's mildly annoying to see an answer which makes no sense, but then keep seeing "an edit has been made..." popping up literally every 30 seconds as the user *actually* slowly begins to answer.

So is there a "correct" (or useful) way to address this? As I mentioned, downvotes and negative comments are occasionally met with hostility, and are of course soon rendered obsolete by the edits, but it is still irritating for those of us reading questions and answers shortly after they were posted.

I realise that this is all quite fuzzy (as quick edits immediately after answering are invaluable), so maybe its just something I need to get over :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you were going to ask about people writing "This is very urgent" in the question. :-)